# Websocket connection with vuex

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuex

I have a Vue app using Vuex as store. I have incoming messages via Websocket updating the state. I tried a few things to have my connection reestablished when it is closed and came up with this solution. It works but it does not really look satisfying and feels wrong.

This is my App.vue:

```js
<template>
  my template
</template>

<script>
function connect(app) {
  app.socket = new WebSocket(process.env.VUE_APP_WS_BACKEND_URL);

  app.socket.onmessage = event => {
    // get data and store with app.$store.commit(..)
  };

  app.socket.onclose = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      connect(app);
    }, 1000);
  };

  app.socket.onerror = () => {
    app.socket.close();
  };
}

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      socket: null
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    connect(this);
  }
};
</script>
```

Does this lead to unwanted behaviour or somehow kill performance or fill up the memory over time or is there just a clean solution I missed?

Comment: this code can not run in vuex right now. how is this websocket running in vuex? You are trying to run in some page your websocket.

Comment: what do you exactly mean? In my main.js file i do `createApp(App).use(store).mount('#app');`

Comment: okey. I understood. but I have a advice for you, you don't use cdn format of vue.js. you install `vue cli` to your computer. and you can create your vue.js project following this link `https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/real-world-vue-js/vue-cli/`

Comment: are you talking about the lifecycle hooks? i am currently rewriting a vue2 app. those will be updated ;)